# Session.remove() in hibernate doesn't delete the entity, but I can't "session.get()" it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

1. I call `session.get(User.class, 11)` and retrieve a user from the DB;
2. I mark this user for removal by calling `session.remove(user)` ;

(note that at this point Hibernate hasn't made a DELETE request to the DB, so the user is still in both the DB and the `persistenceContext` object)

3. I call `session.get(User.class, 11)` again and get a null

My question is: Why am I getting null if the the user still exxists in the DB and first-level cache?

Here's my Main class code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HiberUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    User user = session.get(User.class, 11);  <--- not null
    session.remove(user);
    user = session.get(User.class, 11);       <--- null

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here's my User configuration class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    @Embedded
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
}
```

Comment: `remove` is not "Mark for removal", it's an immediate delete.

Comment: "Immediate delete" from where? The entity only gets deleted from the DB upon flush, transaction commit or when you close the session, while `remove` merely marks it for removal, by putting it in `HashSet nullifiableEntityKeys`. Until one of the three mentioned scenarios has happened, the entity remains in the DB

Comment: Did you mean `session.evict(...)` instead of `remove()`?  I can't find a `remove()` method in the Javadoc for `org.hibernate.Session`.  Or, are you using a different library?

Comment: @VsevolodIV transactional delete from the database. The session reflects the state of the transaction, so you won't see the physical delete until the commit, but the delete will be visible inside the session/transaction after it's issued.

Comment: Jim, you might be looking at the older version, here's the link to 6.4: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html

Comment: teppic, I noticed that when I call `remove` the entity is added to `nullifiableEntityKeys`. Is it possible that before retrieving the entity from the first-level cache , the entity is looked up in  `nullifiableEntityKeys`? I'm trying to figure out why exactly I can't get it from the FLC.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` or `UPDATE` queries requires new sessions while `CREATE` and `READ` queries can reuse one session.

This is from my observation when working with a service that performs all `CRUD` queries.

Note also in Spring-Data-JPA, `DELETE` & `UPDATE` queries usually have `@Transactional` & `Modifying` annotations which creates new sessions